# Web Scraping Risk Factors from 10-K EDGAR

Tags: html, python-3.x, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Is there anyone who has tried to extract the individual risk factors from the Risk Factors section i.e. Item 1A from the EDGAR 10-K filings of the company using BeautifulSoup or any other web scraping library along with using Regular Expressions.

It would be much helpful if you can provide github or pseudo code or atleast some headstart so that I can move forward.

EDIT:
Some examples of 10-Ks

1. https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1350653/000156459018005156/atec-10k_20171231.htm
2. https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1591890/000149315218003887/form10-k.htm
3. https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/750574/000119312518080325/d472492d10k.htm
4. https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/773840/000093041318000292/c89913_10k.htm
5. https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/12927/000001292718000007/a201712dec3110k.htm

I have given more than 1 example because the HTML code is so much random in all of them that using single type of RegEx is tough.

Comment: Can you share URL of sample 10-K filling which contains Section 1A?

Comment: I have edited the question pls check.

Comment: What information do you need to extract? The whole 1A section as a text?

Comment: Yes, text between Item 1A. Risk Factors to Item 1B. and the text in between is divided in parts by the headings (maybe bold or italic) where all those have different theme. So I need to extract all those part in different text files.

Answer (score 1):

I spent a lot of time trying to develop a methodology using REGEX and had some limited success. The problem is that the underlying XML submitted to the SEC does not strictly adhere to standard, and many reports deviate from the report format used. Sometimes they'll use capital case, title case, or use different combinations of letters and numbers to delineate sections. Sometimes they'll include introductory paragraphs to provide additional context to the risks they're about to list. There are so many random factors that interfere with the ability to establish any kind of pattern to the document structure that it's currently more efficient to parse these by human than machine. But, there are thousands upon thousands of documents, making this a very tedious, expensive and drawn out process. One method that might be useful is Amazon's Mechanical Turk, but that would still likely require a lot of upfront development time and could lead to cost restrictions unless the project is well funded.

Answer (score 0):

I had to solve the same problem and I ended up developing a 10-K section extractor from scratch that is able to extract all 10-K sections, including Risk Factors in Item 1A.

The Python example below extracts Item 1, Risk Factors, and returns either the HTML or raw text of the extracted section. The extractor normalizes all Unicode and HTML entities. For example, `&nbsp;` character entities and HTML entities `&NonBreakingSpace;` are replaced with their numeric counterpart `&#160;`. Unicode entities, such as `U+00AF`, are also normalized to their numeric equivalent, i.e. `&#175;`.

The extractor is able to convert the HTML section to raw text. In this case, all HTML and XBRL tags as well as HTML comments are removed. HTML table tags are replaced with two special tokens `##TABLE_START` (=`<table ...>`) and `##TABLE_END` (=`</table>`) to help with parsing (or ignoring) tables.

The filing URL can be of any format. This means, the extractor translates a `.html`, `.txt` and even `-index.htm` and `.xsd` URL to its original filing URL. That's handy if you're relying on `.idx` master files to build up your local database of 10-K URLs. For example, the following is a list of all possible URLs representing the same filing:

- [sec.gov/.../1350653/000156459018005156/atec-10k_20171231.htm](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1350653/000156459018005156/atec-10k_20171231.htm)
- [sec.gov/.../1350653/0001564590-18-005156.txt](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1350653/0001564590-18-005156.txt)
- [sec.gov/.../1350653/000156459018005156/0001564590-18-005156.txt](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1350653/000156459018005156/0001564590-18-005156.txt)
- [sec.gov/.../1350653/000156459018005156/0001564590-18-005156-index.html](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1350653/000156459018005156/0001564590-18-005156-index.html)

The extractor is a behemoth using many different natural language processing algorithms to handle the variety of 10-K structures you already encountered.

All five of your example filings are working out of the box.

### Python Example

```py
# pip install sec-api
from sec_api import ExtractorApi
extractorApi = ExtractorApi("YOUR_API_KEY")

filing_url = "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1350653/000156459018005156/atec-10k_20171231.htm"

# get the standardized HTML of section 1A "Risk Factors"
section_html = extractorApi.get_section(filing_url, "1A", "html")

# get the standardized and cleaned text of section 1A "Risk Factors"
section_text = extractorApi.get_section(filing_url, "1A", "text")
```

### Extracted HTML of Item 1A, Risk Factors (Preview)

[image]

### Extracted Text of Item 1A, Risk Factors

```
Item 1A. 
Risk Factors 

Investing in our common stock involves a high degree of risk. You should carefully consider the following risk factors and all other information contained or incorporated by reference in this Annual Report on Form 10-K. The risks and uncertainties described below are not the only ones facing us. Additional risks and uncertainties that we are unaware of, or that we currently deem immaterial, also may become important factors that affect us. If any of such risks or the risks described below, either alone or taken together, occur, our business, financial condition or results of operations could be materially and adversely affected. In that case, the trading price of our common stock could decline, and you may lose some or all of your investment.

Risks Related to Our Business and Industry

Our business plan relies on certain assumptions pertaining to the market for our products that, if incorrect, may adversely affect our growth and profitability.

We allocate our design, development, marketing, management and financial resources based on our business plan, which includes assumptions about various demographic trends and trends in the treatment of spine disorders and the resulting demand for our products. However, these trends are uncertain. There can be no assurance that our assumptions with respect to an aging population with broad medical coverage and longer life expectancy, which we expect to lead to increased spinal injuries and degeneration, are accurate. In addition, an increasing awareness and use of non-invasive means for the prevention and treatment of back pain and rehabilitation purposes may reduce demand for, or slow the growth of sales of, spine fusion products. A significant shift in technologies or methods used in the treatment of back pain or damaged or diseased bone and tissue could adversely affect demand for some or all of our products. For example, pharmaceutical advances could result in non-surgical treatments gaining more widespread acceptance as a viable alternative to spine fusion. The emergence of new biological or synthetic materials to facilitate regeneration of damaged or diseased bone and to repair damaged tissue could increasingly minimize or delay the need for spine fusion surgery and provide other biological alternatives to spine fusion. New surgical procedures could diminish demand for some of our products. The increased acceptance of emerging technologies that do not require spine fusion, such as artificial discs and nucleus replacement, for the surgical treatment of spine disorders would reduce demand for, or slow the growth of sales of, spine fusion products. If our assumptions regarding these factors prove to be incorrect or if alternative treatments to those offered by our products gain further acceptance, then demand for our products could be significantly less than we anticipate and we may not be able to achieve or sustain growth or profitability.

We are in a highly competitive market segment, face competition from large, well-established medical device companies with significant resources, and may not be able to compete effectively.

The market for spine fusion products and procedures is intensely competitive, subject to rapid technological change and significantly affected by new product introductions and other market activities of industry participants. In 2016, a significant percentage of global spine implant product revenues was generated by Medtronic Sofamor Danek, a subsidiary of Medtronic, Inc.; Depuy Spine, a subsidiary of Johnson &#38; Johnson; and Stryker Spine. Our competitors also include numerous other publicly-traded and privately-held companies such as NuVasive, Zimmer, Biomet, Globus, K2M Medical and SeaSpine.

Several of our competitors enjoy competitive advantages over us, including:

##TABLE_START &#160;

&#8226; 

more established relationships with spine surgeons; 

##TABLE_END
```

### Complete list of all 10-K items

- 1 - Business
- 1A - Risk Factors
- 1B - Unresolved Staff Comments
- 2 - Properties
- 3 - Legal Proceedings
- 4 - Mine Safety Disclosures
- 5 - Market for Registrant’s Common Equity, Related Stockholder Matters and Issuer Purchases of Equity Securities
- 6 - Selected Financial Data (prior to February 2021)
- 7 - Management’s Discussion and Analysis of Financial Condition and Results of Operations
- 7A - Quantitative and Qualitative Disclosures about Market Risk
- 8 - Financial Statements and Supplementary Data
- 9 - Changes in and Disagreements with Accountants on Accounting and Financial Disclosure
- 9A - Controls and Procedures
- 9B - Other Information
- 10 - Directors, Executive Officers and Corporate Governance
- 11 - Executive Compensation
- 12 - Security Ownership of Certain Beneficial Owners and Management and Related Stockholder Matters
- 13 - Certain Relationships and Related Transactions, and Director Independence
- 14 - Principal Accountant Fees and Services